# Azure deployement stucked

Tags: azure

I am trying to publish a project created using .net core and react template in visual studio 2022. I have free Azure account.Yesterday when i tried to publish it showed published successfully but webpage said page not found. so i delted all the resource groups and tried to runn again from start. Now each time when i try to deploy the project using visual studio it stucks . the ones were taking forever yesterday appeared to be failed to and now again i am trying to publish its stucked again.if I go to portal and check operation details it shows :

```
{
    "status": "Failed",
    "error": {
        "code": "429",
        "message": "App Service Plan Create operation is throttled for subscription e61f2058-8c9f-4f13-929c-7527c299df36. Please contact support if issue persists.",
        "details": [
            {
                "message": "App Service Plan Create operation is throttled for subscription e61f2058-8c9f-4f13-929c-7527c299df36. Please contact support if issue persists."
            },
            {
                "code": "429"
            },
            {}
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Yugraaj Sandhu i guess you are hitting the limit of Azure for creating App Service plans, can you check that and also let me know if you are using a free tier.

Comment: Hi Mohd.i guess yess coz I just signed up for free trial yesterday. I am new to azure.what is the solution? .thank you so much for reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigate to the Azure Portal (https://portal.azure.com/).
Select your subscription.
Go to "Usage + quotas" or "Subscriptions" > "Usage + quotas" to review the quotas for your subscription.

In the Azure Portal, navigate to the "App Service plans" section and check the resource utilization of your existing App Service plans.
Look for any plans that might be consuming a significant portion of the allocated resources.

If you are hitting the subscription limits in your case this might happen because of free trail, the best way to get it is by raising a support req in azure.
Follow this link and create a supp req.

https://portal.azure.com/#view/Microsoft_Azure_Support/NewSupportRequestV3Blade/callerWorkflowId/814d8e02-ee4c-4c34-9c6d-af05d14bcf76/callerName/Microsoft_Azure_Support%2FHelpAndSupportOverview.ReactView